# In spring boot how to load a yml section as java.util.Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, I have following configuration:

```
server:
  host: a.com
  port: 5922
  enable-log: true
```

I want to read the above as a `java.util.Properties`. I tried putting following class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class ServerConfig {
  private Properties serverProps;
  // ... Getter/setter
}
```

The boot config files look like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ServerConfig.class})
@Profile({"dev"})
public class TestAppConfiguration {
}

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestAppInitializer {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestAppInitializer.class, args);
  }
}
```

Unit test class:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestAppInitializer.class})
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class ServerConfigTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
  @Autowired
  private ServerConfig serverConfig;

  @Test
  public void printDetails() {
    logger.debug("ServerConfig.properties --> {}", serverConfig.getProperties());
  }
}
```

The output is 
**`ServerConfig.properties --> null`**.

I am not sure why is this happening. The only idea that comes to my mind is, the configuration parameters underneath `server` are basically flat strings. Is there any way I can read those as `Properties`?

Comment: You cannot read properies to java.util.Properties class using ConfigurationProperties annotation. You can read them to simple type class variables as String/Integer/Boolean etc.

Comment: Hi @Niranjan , did you find a way to directly set the values in Properties object? we can always create fields and add them to the properties object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't load them into `java.util.Properties` with annotation `@ConfigurationProperties`.

You need to create this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class ServerConfig {
  private String host;
  private String port;
  private String enableLog;
  // ... Getter/setter
}
```

Comment: I had already done this; but I posted the question thinking if anyone has done the `Properties` way. Anyways, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Bean({"kaptchaProperties"})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom.kaptcha")
public Properties getProperties() {
    return new Properties();
}
```

Comment: Perfectly worked for me. I had to load certain entries to java.util.Properties and worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: This is completely counter intuitive to me, when does it add the values?? The getter is returning an empty properties... I'm so confused but it works!