# How to inject prefixed properties into java.util.Properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring boot provides an elegant way to inject the properties prefixed with a particular key into Configuration class using `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")`. That is shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) and [here](http://www.java2novice.com/spring-boot/configurationproperties-example/). Question is, how to inject prefixed properties into `java.util.Properties` instance as shown below?

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka")
    public Producer<String, String> producer(Properties properties) throws Exception {
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        return producer;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does not work, since this property injection is based on getters and setters on the object that should hold the `@ConfigurationProperties`
Define a class holding the properties you want like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka.producer")
public class MyKafkaProducerProperties {

  private int foo;

  private string bar;

  // Getters and Setter for foo and bar

}
```

Then use it in your configuration like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyKafkaProducerProperties.class)
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {

  @Bean
  public Producer<String, String> producer(MyKafkaProducerProperties kafkaProperties) throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("Foo", kafkaProperties.getFoo());
    properties.setProperty("Bar", kafkaProperties.getBar());
    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    return producer;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since you commented that you don't want to have each property represented as java code you could use a `HashMap` as the one and only property in your `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka")
public class MyKafkaProducerProperties {

  private Map<String, String> producer= new HashMap<String, String>();

  public Map<String, String> getProducer() {
    return this.producer;
  }
}
```

In your `application.properties` you can specify the properties like this:

```
kafka.producer.foo=hello
kafka.producer.bar=world
```

And in your configuration you can use it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyKafkaProducerProperties.class)
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {

  @Bean
  public Producer<String, String> producer(MyKafkaProducerProperties kafkaProperties) throws Exception {

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    for ( String key : kafkaProperties.getProducer().keySet() ) {
     properties.setProperty(key, kafkaProperties.getProducer().get(key));
    }

    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    return producer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yannnic. I understood why my code wont work. Could you explain a way to inject prefixed properties automatically? This way I can externalize properties without requiring hard coding property names(`setProperty()`).

Comment: The `@Value` annotation does what you want I think. This way you can inject properties to your bean. Have a look at this guide: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: Yes, it does inject properties directly into fields. The KafkaProducer class is from third-party API and I want to pass properties to it as is(provided by application.properties) but prefixed with "kafka", so that any new property can be added without adding new field to `MyKafkaProducerProperties`. Hence I am trying to find an answer to How to inject prefixed properties into java.util.Properties? `PropertySource`?

Comment: Hm maybe you could use a HashMap as field in your configuration properties. I will update my answer. give me a sec

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new bean that is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`, like this:

```java
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka")
public Properties kafkaProperties() {
    return new Properties();
}

@Bean
public Producer<String, String> producer() throws Exception {
    return new KafkaProducer<String, String>(kafkaProperties());
}
```

(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810923/500478)

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired Environment environment;
private Properties getProperties() { return  new Properties() { @Override public String getProperty(String name) { return environment.getProperty(name); } }; }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).